# Correct way to list multiple $query->set

Tags: php, wordpress

What is the correct way to list multiple $query->set ? Am I allowed to have multiple `$query->set` like "CODE A" below ?
Or am I supposed to combine them into one? If yes, how would you combine the three `$query->set` code? I tried combining them in "CODE B" below but it didn't work.

.
**CODE A: Before combine $query->set**

This code goes in functions.php

```
function featured_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'category_name', 'new' );
    $query->set( 'cat', '-60, -61' );
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'featured_category' );
```

.
**CODE B: After combine $query->set**

This code goes in functions.php

```
function featured_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( array( 'category_name' => 'new', 'cat' => '-60, -61', 'posts_per_page' => 5) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'featured_category' );
```

Comment: What you want to do is not clear. can you explain why you want to do $query->set() ? and what make you think it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct way to use the `set` method (which is part of the `WP_Query` class) is to pass 2 parameters - a query parameter key and a query parameter value. So your first example (CODE A) is the correct way to do it.

You can take a look at the method code here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/query.php#L2328

P.S.
If you want to exclude multiple categories from a query, consider using the `category__not_in` query parameters, for example:

```
$query->set( 'category__not_in', array(60, 61) );
```

For more information about category query parameters, check http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

Comment: Is `'cat' => '-60, -61'` incorrect or just not preferred? ---- Just to be clear, `'cat'` does NOT accept arrays ? Therefore you are suggesting `'category__not_in'` ?

Comment: Two more questions. Does it slow down your website if you use so many `$query->set` ? ---- Also, if I wanted to EXCLUDE categories 1,2,3 but specifically INCLUDE categories 4 and 5, is "METHOD A" allowed: `$query->set( 'cat', array(-1, -2, -3, 4, 5) )` ? ---- Or must you do two separate `$query->set` such as "METHOD B": `$query->set( 'category__in', array(4, 5) )` ---- and also ---- `$query->set( 'category__not_in', array(4, 5) )`

Comment: You can answer all you questions by reading the WP_Query documentation that is linked in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, for a more elegant and concise approach. You could group them in an array and loop through them.

```php
<?php

$query_vars = array(
    'post_type' => 'question',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'posts_per_archive_page' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'rand(' . get_query_var( 'docket' ) . ')',
);

foreach ( $query_vars as $key => $value ) {

    $wp_query->set( $key, $value );

};
```