# How to exclude category from homepage by using php function rather than default WP function?

Tags: php, wordpress

I bought a WordPress theme for affiliate marketing business. I have 1000+ stores on my website and hence hundred of coupons on homepage.I simply write a short-code to fetch all coupons and they started to appear on homepage .All coupons are based on different categories.

How can i exclude a number of coupons from homepage and that is possible only if we can exclude some categories from homepage based on their IDs.

I Google it many times but each time i found "pre_get_posts" function to do so. But in my case, it's not working at all. The code is below

```
 function exclude_category_home( $query ) {
            if ( $query->is_home ) {
            $query->set( 'cat', '-5' );
            }
            return $query;
            }
        add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category_home' );
```

Through this code i am trying to exclude desired categories. I also tried to modified above code in different ways but none of my solution/idea worked.
    What i think is the reason behind why above code is no working is the function only works for default "Category" option under "Posts"on Dashboard. And my categories are coming from another option on Dashboard that's "Coupons" -> "Offer Categories".

See screenshot: [Offer Categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5Dv8.png)

May be or may be not, i need to modify the above function in a way that it can select my expected categories. But as i have lack of knowledge in PHP so i don't know what and how to do?

I'm badly stuck here and hoping to get some help from experts.

Thanks in advance

Comment: change this `if ( $query->is_home ) {` to `if (is_home() || is_front_page()) {`

Comment: check if this post helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453908/correct-way-to-list-multiple-query-set

Comment: @Vel Still not working

Comment: seems you are using custom category. so will change instead of `'cat',`

Comment: @Vel  What should i write instead of 'cat' ? i don't know from where i can get the slag for custom category :(

Comment: @Vel Lemme try....

Comment: @Vel Sorry for late reply, If you don't mind , can you please give me a little guide. What values, i will put here? How can i get that values , like for me , the category name is toy.
How would i change below parameters. ?


                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'sold-gallery',
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                ),

Comment: This is what i wrote in my functions.php

function wpse188669_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
if (is_home() || is_front_page()){
        $tax_query = array(
            'post_type' => 'coupons',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'offer_categories',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'freebie',
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                ),
            ),
        );
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse188669_pre_get_posts' );

Comment: @Vel Thanks for your response Sir. My taxonomy is  "taxonomy=offer_categories"
I' m using "clipmydeals" theme in which this is a built-in feature... Really looking forward for your help. Again thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
if(is_home() || is_front_page()){
    $args_active_coupons['tax_query'][] = array( 
    'taxonomy' => 'offer_categories', 
    'field' => 'id', 
    'terms' => array(214), 
    'operator' => 'NOT IN', 
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts. I really want to appreciate Vel, for all his efforts as he gave me more than 5 hours to sort out my problem. He is very good and expert person i ever met on this platform. Highly Recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hard code all the excluded category, you have to put your category ID with (-) prefix. e.g

```
function exclude_category_home( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home ) {
    $query->set( 'cat', '-<CAT_ID>, -<CAT_ID>, -<CAT_ID>' );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category_home' );
```

Here: CAT_ID should be excluded category id.

In another way, you could use a plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-category-excluder/

Comment: @Ibrar Sorry for the misunderstanding. Did you try the plugin?